# Are a Facebook profile and Facebook Page Interconnected?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a Facebook Profile for personal use and a Facebook Page for business use. I want the profile photo to be different on each account. But every time I change one, it also changes on the other. Can I have two different photos for each??

Comment: The 2 that you mentioned are separate from each other and can be managed and setup independently. How are you changing the photos? Are you using the business page as the business page or as yourself? Add more details to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 that you've mentioned, *personal profile* and *business page*, are separate from each other and can be managed and setup independently. You can create your page using [this link](https://www.facebook.com/pages/create).

Then on your right upper corner you can see a star looking button next to *Home* and *Find Friends*. [image]

Here you can choose to use Facebook as the page you've created or as yourself. If you use Facebook as the page then you can do what it is that you need to, like change the profile picture, change the cover picture, post, or whatever.